# How to send logs to logstash through winlogbeat

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, elk, kibana-7

I have installed Winlogbeat on windows 10 (My main OS) and I have installed ELK on ubuntu I want to send logs to ubuntu logstash through winlogbeat but it doesn't show anything when I open kibana. I mean no logs .. I don't know whether there's something wrong with my yml files or there's something wrong with the IPs that are not connecting..

I'll share all yml files and other important stuff needed .. Someone please just get me out of this issue

Comment: I tried all of this as well and it was a royal pain in the southern-end. Rather than using WinLogBeat, we ship out Windows Event Logs to CloudWatch Logs and then stream them to ELK: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_ES_Stream.html

Comment: Update your question with your winlogbeat and elasticsearch configurations.

Comment: I had a similar problem. Please share the logstash and winlogbeat configuration files to see exactly where the problem is. Show us the result of the following command in windows: ```
.\winlogbeat.exe test config -c C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Beats\winlogbeat\winlogbeat.yml -e
```